# Nvidia Driver Help

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I recently installed a Nvidia driver for my gtx 570 in recovery mode since it would not allow xorg to run simultaneously. (`NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.67.run.part`)

After I installed I wanted to make sure my driver was working so I installed Nvidia-settings.

I receive an error stated by `nvidia-settings`:

```
You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver.  
Please edit your X configuration file (just run `nvidia-xconfig` as root), and restart the X server.
```

lspci shows:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF110 [GeForce GTX 570 HD] (rev a1)
```

I am new to Linux and don’t feel as if I would be having this problem if not for my novice
any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.67.run.part ends in .part which shows that it has not been completely downloaded. So, as the error message in your question says, `You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver`, because you haven't installed the Nvidia driver yet.

You can easily install the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver using the Additional Drivers utility as follows:

1. Search the Dash for *Additional Drivers*. Click the Additional Drivers icon to open the Additional Drivers utility.
2. Select the latest version Nvidia graphics driver that has *(proprietary, tested)* appearing after it. For example, if you are using Ubuntu 14.04, the latest version Nvidia graphics driver is version 331 (proprietary, tested). If you are using Ubuntu 12.04, select the Nvidia graphics driver that has *[Recommended]* appearing after it.
3. Click the **Apply Changes** button to install the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver.
4. Reboot the computer to enable the Nvidia graphics driver.